# Debug SQL Server to diagnose DNN site poor speed performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, dotnetnuke

I am experiencing slow speed issues with my DNN site especially on non cached pages. I ran my site on Google's Page Speed Insights and received the following error:

> Reduce server response time - In our test, your server responded in 11.4
>   seconds. There are many factors that can slow down your server
>   response time. Please read our recommendations to learn how you can
>   monitor and measure where your server is spending the most time.

I have tested a few common errors like large database log file size but can't quite figure out what's causing my server to slow down this particular site's performance (other sites on the same server are unaffected).

Any comments are welcome, thanks

Comment: Try this: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/155158/using-sql-profiler-with-dnn

Comment: Also: "especially on non-cached pages" concerns me. You ought to run with enough RAM to pretty much every page is cached.

Comment: Hi Joel, thx for link (will look at now). Sry in relation to 'non cached' I was referring to the slow performance being mostly prominent when cache refreshed (as it speeds up after a page has been visited). Site is more than covered with regards RAM.

Comment: How many hits does the DNN site get? If it's idle for more than 20 minutes it will recycle. The next visit will be slow because all the libraries have to be loaded again. Your comment `as it speeds up after a page has been visited` seems to indicate this. If not we'll look further.

Comment: I have a ping setup to ensure site isn't left idle too long. I disabled the scheduler and it solved the slow responsiveness. I am currently disabling one scheduled task at a time to source specific error but pretty sure its either the search site/file crawler. First issue in identifying nearly there, next up is actually fixing it.... thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in the end was to clear the contents of the /app data/search folder and re-index the host contents (Host set.>Adv. set.>Search settings>Re-index). No issue persists with the Search crawler scheduler job as a result